# I installed the Stamps.com Connect to my computer and I can't uninstall

Tags: applications, menu-bar

I installed the Stamps.com Connect to my OS X Macbook. I cannot get rid of the stupid thing. I cancelled my subscription the day I created it but I cannot get the icon off of my menu bar not can I delete it from my applications. I have not been able to use the command key to drag the icon because that just opens it in the menu bar. In the applications file, it will not let me delete it because "it is in use." I am at my wits end. Please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your application is probably running in background, so you have to "kill it" before you can uninstall it.

Using [Activity Monitor](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201464), find the *Stamps.com Connect* process and double click on it (using Acrobat as an example because I don't have Stamps.com; the process is the same, however).

[image]

You will then be presented with another dialog which will allow you to quit the running process:

[image]

Select "Quit."

You should then be able to uninstall the software.  As for uninstalling it, I recommend using [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/).  I have used it for many years and it has been successful in removing even the most stubborn of Apps.  Plus, it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the application is closed by clicking on the menu bar icon and clicking "quit" (or something similar) and delete it from Applications. Can also use “activity monitor”.

You could also search "login items" in spotlight and turn off the app from auto launching if it's there and then try restarting your computer.

*This has been said to be false but I would try*: Also be sure you ejected the installer. You can find it in finder on the left, otherwise it may be on the desktop.

Comment: Why am I getting downvotes?

Comment: Didn't downvote, but the answer is basically incorrect.  The installer will have nothing to do with the running app.  Your advice to quit is on the right track, but a bit vague on how to accomplish

Comment: Clicking on menu item does nothing except launch the website. @Allan is correct on the Quit process. You can remove the login item in Preferences>Users & Groups>Login Items. Select Stamps.com connect and hit the minus sign at the bottom. Then delete the Stamps.com Connect file from your Applications directory.